# real solution of eqn. in $\sin x+2\sin 2x-\sin 3x = 3,$ where $x\in (0,\pi)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The no. of real solution of the equation $\sin x+2\sin 2x-\sin 3x = 3,$ where $x\in (0,\pi)$.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\left(\sin x-\sin 3x\right)+2\sin 2x = 3$

$\Rightarrow -2\cos 2x\cdot \sin x+2\sin 2x = 3\Rightarrow -2\cos 2x\cdot \sin x+4\sin x\cdot \cos x = 3$

$\Rightarrow 2\sin x\cdot \left(-\cos 2x+2\cos x\right)=3$

Now I did not understand how can i solve it.

Help me

Thanks

Comment: I have the strange feeling that there is no real root to this equation. Are you sure that the rhs is $3$ and not $2$ or something else ?

Comment: To   Claude Leibovici actually it is $3$ on $R.H.S$

Comment: Can anyone have a solution using Inequality.Thanks

Comment: Could you precise what do you mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x\\{}\\\sin 3x=\sin2x\cos x+\sin x\cos2x=2\sin x\cos^2x+\sin x(1-2\sin^2x)\end{cases}$$

Thus we get

$$0=\sin x+4\sin x\cos x-2\sin x\cos^2x-\sin x+2\sin^3x$$

Divide al through by $\;\sin x\;$ (why can we?):

$$4\cos x-2\cos^2x+2\sin^2x=0\iff2\cos x-\cos^2x+1-\cos^2x=0\iff$$

$$2\cos^2x-2\cos x-1=0\iff \ldots$$

Comment: You have got a typo in your last equation. +1!

Comment: @DonAntonio, Where is the $3$ (which is in the Right hand side of the Question) in your answer?

Comment: Nice Solution DonAntonio. Can any one explain it to me using Inequality.Thanks

Comment: @juantheron, I've no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\sin x+2\sin 2x-\sin 3x = 3\Rightarrow (\sin 2x-1)^2+(\cos 2x+\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2=0\; \forall x\in (0,\pi)$

So either $\sin 2x = 1$ and  $\cos 2x = -\sin x$ and $\cos x=0$

So from above no common value of $x\in (0,\pi)$ for which above equation is satisfied.

So no real values of $x$

Answer (score 1):

**Using Inequality**

Starting from $\bf{L.H.S\;\;}$

$$\sin x+2\sin 2x-\sin 3x = -2\sin x\cos 2x+2\sin 2x\leq \left|2\sin x\cos 2x+2\sin 2x\right|$$

$$\leq 2|\sin 2x+\cos 2x|\leq 2\sqrt{2}\left|\sin \left(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|\leq 2\sqrt{2}<3\;(\bf{R.H.S})$$

So no real values of $x$ for which $\sin x+2\sin 2x-\sin 3x =3\;\forall x\in (0,\pi)$